# How to create a function that returns a new array containing duplicate values of another array

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a problem that returns a  new double array containing duplicated values from another double array. I cannot use HashSets or ArrayLists in this problem. I tried using a brunt force method of swapping indexes from the original array and the new array I made. However, I am not getting expected results. I attached a screenshot of my code and the output I get. Example results, if  this function is correct, include: new double [ ] {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88} < --removeDuplicates(new double [ ] {11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 33, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 55, 55, 66, 77, 88, 88})[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHGzL.png)

Comment: My screenshot is the "enter image description here" link. Thanks!

Comment: Don't show us your code in screenshots.  Copy and paste the relevant parts into the question, and format them using the Markdown syntax provided.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've read a solution to your question in http://www.GeekersforGeeks.org. Here I included what I've found so far. In the following code, in removeDuplicates function, a temporary double array is created and it's used to hold the new array after removing duplicates.

The logic used here is pretty simple. First, it checks whether the given array has no elements or only one element, and if it is, it just returns the array, as there is no duplication.

Then it starts traversing through elements and if tow nearby elements are not equal ( means if elements are unique ) then those elements are stored in the new temp[] array. If the duplicates are found they are ignored and not stored in the temp[] array.

Finally, it stores the last element of the given array into temp[] array.

Then it modifies the original array using the temp[] array and returns the original array without duplications.

```
static int removeDuplicates(double arr[], int n) 
{ 
    // return the array itself, if it is empty or contains only one element
    if (n==0 || n==1) 
        return n; 

    //creating a temporary array to hold new array data
    double[] temp = new double[n]; 

    // Start traversing elements 
    int j = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) 

        //checking for duplicates and store elements in 
        //temp[] array if not duplicated.
        if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]) 
            temp[j++] = arr[i]; 

    // Store the last element as whether 
    // it is unique or repeated, it hasn't 
    // stored previously 
    temp[j++] = arr[n-1];    

    // Modify original array 
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++) 
        arr[i] = temp[i]; 

    return j; 
}
```